# Python PyQt5 запуск Qt Designer в Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6, qt-designer

PyQt5 поставил так: pip3 install PyQt5 - установился нормально.
Но как запустить Qt Designer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Поищите в `<папка python>\Library\bin\designer.exe`

---

Если его там нет, попробуйте установить: `pip install pyqt5-tools`.

Тогда дизайнер искать в: `<папка python>\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer.exe`

---

Если python установлен, но не знаете его путь, можно попробовать узнать у него самого, введя в консоли:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Comment: поискал  - нет его там

Comment: возможно, его туда мне положил pyqt4 или pyside, которые раньше устанавливал.

Comment: в site-packages есть только папка PyQt5, но в ней тоже нет

Comment: `Если его там нет, попробуйте установить: pip install pyqt5-tools.`? Только что установил pyqt5-tools и в site-packages\pyqt5-tools нашел дизайнер

Comment: Да, получилось. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Может быть вы смотрели в папке с установленным *Python*, а не в документах:
 `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python... pyqt5_tools\ Qt\ bin`

Нашел там, после совета с установкой через команду: `pip install pyqt5-tools` 
от пользователя выше.

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя с трудом нашел вот по такому пути:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Скриншот результатов поиска на ПК через WoX]

Так как с недавних пор можно установить интерпретатор питона версии 3.9 с магазина Windows Store, питон может у кого-то, кто так и сделал, являться приложением магазина со всеми вытекающими. Потому, не смотря на, возможно, до сих пор актуальные предыдущие мне ответы, оставлю свои два варианта. Во втором варианте отличие от предыдущих ответов - папка "qt5_applications".

Установка выполнялась посредством исполнения команд: `pip install pyqt5 | pip install pyqt5-tools` (была оф. версия 3.7.7) и `pip3.9 install pyqt5 | pip3.9 install pyqt5-tools` (версия 3.9 скачана приложением из Windows Store, команды исполнялись в PowerShell от имени Администратора)

1: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe`

2: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe`

Актуально для Windows 10, но смею предположить, что и для "Семёрки" также будет актуально за исключением того, что в ней, как мне помнится, нет и не было магазина Windows Store.

Comment: спасибо большое